# Is silencer's intelligence steal talent retroactive?

Tags: dota-2

Title mostly says it all, would you immediately steal an extra X int from everyone you've previously stolen int from on leveling the talent, or does it only make you steal more int for all the kills/assists you're a part of after leveling the talent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The talent is not retroactive, it will only steal more intelligence from the moment it is chosen.